# Leetcode problem: minimum removal to make valid parentheses

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge, balanced-delimiters

I was working on [this problem on leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-remove-to-make-valid-parentheses/)

> ### Question
>
> Your task is to remove the minimum number of parentheses ( '(' or
> ')', in any positions ) so that the resulting parentheses string is
> valid and return any valid string.
>
> Formally, a parentheses string is valid if and only if:
>
> It is the empty string, contains only lowercase characters, or
>
> It can be written as AB (A concatenated with B), where A and B are
> valid strings, or
>
> It can be written as (A), where A is a valid string.
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: s = "lee(t(c)o)de)"
> Output: "lee(t(c)o)de"
> Explanation: "lee(t(co)de)" , "lee(t(c)ode)" would also be accepted.
> ```
>
> Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input: s = "))(("
> Output: ""
> Explanation: An empty string is also valid.
> ```

### My Solution

```
var minRemoveToMakeValid = function(s) {
let myStack = [];
let myObj = {}; // for storing index having invalid parentheses to be removed
let out = '';

  // O(n)??
  for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
      let val = s[i]
      if(["(", ")"].includes(val)){
          if(val == ')' && myStack[myStack.length -1]?.char == "("){
              const rem = myStack.pop()
              delete myObj[rem.index]
          } else {
              myStack.push({
                  char: val,
                  index: i
              })
              myObj[i] = true
          }
      }
  }

  // O(n)
  for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
      if(!myObj[i]){
          out += s[i]
      }
  }
  return out 
};
```

Isn't the above solution in O(N) time complexity?
It seems so to me however the results show that it is not (the solution runtime is in bottom 8% percentile)

Why is this having such bad runtime even it seems like O(N)? or is it not so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Performance

Your function is not O(*n*), because of the `out += s[i]` when constructing the result.  Since JavaScript strings are immutable, every time you perform such a concatenation, it must construct a new string, which involves copying the `out` that it has constructed so far.  When you do that in a loop, it becomes O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

Instead, you want to work on an array, then use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to build the resulting string all at once.

### Data structures

`myObj` is the least informative name you could possibly pick for a variable.  A better name might be `isInvalidPos`.

`myStack` is also not a wonderful name, but it does have the advantage of stating your intention to use the array as a stack.  You use it to store all occurrences of `(` and `)`, but really, you only care about storing `(`, since the only place where you inspect the contents is `myStack[myStack.length -1]?.char == "("`.  So, in my suggested solution below, I've turned it into `openParenPosStack`.

Instead of building `myObj`, then writing a second loop that uses it to build `out` (the loop with the performance problem), why not build the output in the main loop?

### Suggested solution

```js
var minRemoveToMakeValid = function(s) {
    let openParenPosStack = [];                 // indexes of outstanding open parens
    let out = new Array(s.length);              // array of valid characters in output
    
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        switch (s[i]) {
        case '(':
            openParenPosStack.push(i);
            break;                              // assume invalid, until a close paren is encountered
        case ')':
            if (!openParenPosStack.length) {
                break;                          // close without matching open is invalid
            }
            out[openParenPosStack.pop()] = '('; // retroactively make the open paren valid
            // fall through
        default:
            out[i] = s[i];                      // valid close paren, or misc character
        }
    }
    
    return out.join('');
};

console.log(minRemoveToMakeValid("lee(t(c)o)de)"));
console.log(minRemoveToMakeValid("))(("));
```

Comment: Thanks. Your final solution has much better TC results. 
However, just for sake of testing I replaced the string `out += s[i]` with `out.push(s[i])`, keeping everything else same (`out` is now an array, I do `return out.join('')` at the end). But still there is no difference in time taken by my program. Why is that?

Comment: Also, i don't really understand how this line in your code is working : `out[openParenPosStack.pop()] = '('` can you please explain more

Comment: Just a guess about the performance issue: did you allocate the array with the size hint like I did, with `let out = new Array(s.length)`? Or did you simply write `let out = []`, in which case `out.push(s[i])` could still require a reallocation and copy?

Comment: `out[openParenPosStack.pop()] = '('` does just what the comment says. Since `openParenPosStack.pop()` returns the index of the last `'('` seen in `s` that hasn't already been matched by a valid `')'`, it retroactively copies that `'('` from `s` to `out` at that position.

Comment: Tried both ways ... pretty similar results in both cases. Actually performs better with `let out = [ ]`. 
Regarding the explanation, doesn't `pop()` function return the value popped out? How do you get the index from output of pop? Maybe i'm missing something?